# Class invariant of a size-limited stack

Tags: java, class, invariants

I am currently working on data structures and object-oriented contracts, especially in Java.

I am wondering what a class invariant of a size-constrained stack could be. If I understand the concept of an invariant correctly, this invariant must be true throughout the execution of the program to prove the correctness of the program, right?

As an example, let's assume that this size-constrained stack contains elements of the data type Person. My idea for an invariant now would be:

```
assert limitNotReached();
```

limitNotReached() returns true if the maximum size of the stack has not yet been reached, otherwise false.

Is this a good invariant or does anyone have a better idea/suggestion for improvement?

Comment: The only (size-relates) invariant of a size-limited stack is that its size doesn't exceed the limit. (And is non-negative, I guess).

Answer (score 1):

A data structure is a very poor choice to demonstrate the concept of a class invariant. It’s a data structure, which holds things, but isn’t a “thing” itself, so there’s no particular invariant that make much sense.

A better example would be say a Car class that has an invariant condition that its fuel level can never be negative.